# My vstest custom adapter is not found during discovery

Tags: vstest, vstest.console.exe, dotnet-test, vstest.console

I'm trying to get vstest to recognize a simple test adapter I've created following the directions [here](https://github.com/microsoft/vstest/blob/main/docs/RFCs/0004-Adapter-Extensibility.md). I run `dotnet test` with the parameters as follows:

> C:\Users\yozep\source\repos\yozepi\Specs>dotnet test "Examples\ConsoleExample\bin\Debug\net6.0\ConsoleExample.dll" --TestAdapterPath:"Examples\ConsoleExample\bin\Debug\net6.0" --ListExecutors
> Microsoft (R) Test Execution Command Line Tool Version 17.0.0
> Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.
>
> The following Test Execution Add-Ins are available:
>
> C:\Users\yozep\source\repos\yozepi\Specs>

As you can see, no add-in's are found. I added the NUnit3TestAdapter as a sanity check but the NUnit adapter cannot be found either. I've confirmed both the NUnit adapter dll and my dll are both in directory `"Examples\ConsoleExample\bin\Debug\net6.0"`.

What am I missing?